# Есть ли стандарт для структуры spring проектов?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Есть моменты когда нужно подсмотреть ту или иную реализацию на github, но очень часто вижу разную структуру пакетов, что иногда меня вводит в тупик.

К примеру:

```java
entity //Часто названия пакетов model или domain
controller //Иногда пакет называется rest, api, web, даже resource встречал
```

Но если к этим можно привыкнуть то с названиями пакетов ниже я уж точно запутался:

```
repository // Иногда классы в пакете dao
dao или service // Обычно в проекте есть пакет либо service либо dao, но иногда есть и тот и другой
```

- Хотелось бы понять **dao** и **service** это одно и тоже только разные названия пакетов (директорий) ?
- Есть ли какой-то общий стандарт структуры spring проекта ? *(иногда в самих доках spring разная структура)*
- Правильно ли в случае непонятного мне класса ориентироваться на аннотацию в классе ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единого стандарта именования пакетов нет. Но есть разумные принципы. Название пакета должно чётко передавать назначение предметной области и отношения с другими пакетами в иерархии. Об этом можно почитать у Мартина в "Чистом коде" например. Впрочем, огрехи с именованием встречаются даже в стандартной библиотеке.